# Shiny "loading" data into numericInput-field

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to this forum and Shiny in general, so I do my best in asking my question, but feel free to ask any additional info I forgot to provide or give feedback to improve my questions in the future.

I wrote a little program in shiny in which I use two `numericInput` functions to set a Gate (lower and upper border basically). Now I would like to store these gates to use them for other data sets or in other tabs. Saving them seemed the easy part, but I could not make it work to load them back into the `numericInput` field.

I made it work to bypass the `numericInput` field by using the if-operation, so that my program uses the global gate instead of the `numericInput` value (also made that selectable with a check-box) but the real goal would be to put the data back into the `numeriInput` field to be able to make small adjustments to the global gate for each data set without having to type the gate again into the field.

I don't know if that is at all possible, but if it is I hope someone here knows the answer.

I created this small piece of code as an example how it should look like in the end, but without knowing how to make the "Get Global"-Button work.

```
server <- function(input, output){
  observe({
    if (input$setglobal==0){
      return()
    }

    isolate({
      global <- input$input1
      output$displayglobal <- renderText(global)
      })
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6, numericInput("input1", label="Lower Gate", value=0, step = 1),
  actionButton("setglobal", "Set as Global"), actionButton("getglobal", "Get Global")),
  column(6, h3("Global Value: "), textOutput("displayglobal"))
  )


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

`reactiveValues()` is a great way to store data that you need to use other places within a shiny server. It functions like a list, but changes to the values triggers reactivity based on them. Here is a short example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("input",
             numericInput(inputId = 'input1', label = "Number", value = 0)
             ),
    tabPanel("output",
             textOutput("displayGlobal")
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  vals <- reactiveValues(number = NULL)

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$input1,
               handlerExpr = {
                 vals$number <- input$input1
               })

  output$displayGlobal <- renderText(paste0("Your Number is: ", vals$number))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think this part I got, but what I want to do is make a numericInput on the second Tab, which can have the Value from the first Tab loaded into it via a button. But from my research now i think that might not work since shiny might not allow changing input values.